# How can I style the arrow of react select component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, react-select

I'm looking to add a blue background and color the downward arrow icon in my react select component. However I can't seem to find the right method to target the pieces of the select I'm looking to change at the moment the select looks like....

[image]

And I'd like it to be more like.....

[image]

My code is currently ...

```
  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    return (
      <Select
        value={selectedOption}
        styles={reactSelectStyles}
        onChange={this.passingprops}
        options={this.state.adminoptions}
      />
    );

  }
}

const reactSelectStyles = {
  icon: {
    fill: "blue"
  }
}
```

Am I going in the right direction or have I missed the mark entirely? I feel there is a simple solution to this I just can't quite get there.

Thanks all!

Comment: try use `dropdownIndicator` instead of 'icon' for dropdown button. and `backgroundColor` instead of `fill`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to override the styles of the `dropdownIndicator`.

```
const dropdownIndicatorStyles = (base, state) => {
  let changes = {
    // all your override styles
    backgroundColor: 'blue';
  };
  return Object.assign(base, changes);
};

<Select styles={{dropdownIndicator: dropdownIndicatorStyles}} />
```

You'll have to play with it some, but hopefully you get the gist. If you want to know what styles are already applied, just introspect `base` in your debugger. The [Documentation](https://react-select.com/home) gives some examples as well.

Comment: This is great thank you very much! I can see now where I should have been looking to make this happen. Thanks for your example!

Answer (score 1):

It looks much simpler and works :)

```
const colourStylesRow = {
  dropdownIndicator: styles => ({ 
    ...styles, 
    color: '#FFAE12', 
  })
}

<Select
  styles={colourStylesRow}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, you solved my problem.

```
const customStyles = {
    dropdownIndicator: (base, state) => {
      let changes = {
        padding: 0,
      };
      return Object.assign(base, changes);
    },

    control: (base) => ({
      ...base,
      height: 0,
      minHeight: 28,
    }),
    IndicatorsContainer: (base) => ({
      ...base,
      minHeight: 1,
    }),
  };
```